# IPC Suggestion for lots of small data

Tags: java, ipc, rmi, multiprocessing

We are going to implement a *multi-process* software and we are looking for a proper IPC.

Facts:

- We are going to use Java (and C if we face something time critical)

  All the processes are on a single Unix machine.

  The processes sends each other lots (about 1000) of small (about 4k) data per second.

What IPC tech do you recommend? Web services, RMI, TCP Sockets, Unix Sockets, Pipes, ...?

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock (just because it's the first name in the "closed as off-topic by" list and only one user can be notified) or anyone: is there another site in the SE network where this question could be asked ?  (I already know it can't at Software Recommendations). I need to ask basically the same question.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479593/which-java-rmi-rpc-ipc-technology-should-i-use) may be useful as it's asking the same thing - except for the "small data" part - and it got several answers. I'm not sure why this one is off-topic and that one is not, but although that one is a bit old it has the info I was looking for when I found this one.

Comment: Web services are built atop TCP, so I'm going to ignore the "web" part and simply point out that TCP is overkill. Most of the services it provides to higher-layer protocols (flow control, congestion control, in-order delivery, reliability, process addressing) assume an unreliable underlying channel. In the case of local connections, the majority of that overhead is unnecessary. The services provided by IP are unnecessary because you don't really need multiple NICs to communicate. UNIX sockets were written to provide TCP-like functionality without the overhead of an actual network session.

Comment: So that brings us to RMI, Unix sockets, pipes, and shared memory maps (with semaphores or- if you're really clever- lockless concurrent data structures).

Comment: However, before we even get to analysis of those, worthwhile to quickly check... Are you using multiple processes instead of JNI, or are they multiple Java + C hybrid processes working together?

Comment: (Oh! And I forgot about FIFO files. And message queues... Y'know what? Asking a new question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the above could do this. 1000/s isn't that much (even for 4 KB)

I would add Active MQ and ZeroMQ to the list.

I would use https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle Why? because I wrote it. ;) You might to try something else.